# trying to make a carousel slider in django and trying to take picture from database then render on frontend

Tags: django, django-templates, slider, carousel

I am trying to make a carousel slider. Picture comes from the database and then render it on the frontend slider. But the picture is rendering but it is creating new slider and when i change to next slide then it shows the same picture. What to do??

My code is here...

```
`{% for post in object_list %}
    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>
</ul>

<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="{{ post.image.url}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="{{ post.title }}">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="{{ post.title }}">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="{{ post.title }}">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point inside your `views.py` file you passed a `context` to your template for rendering, likely looking something like so:

```py
post = ...
return render(request, "template_name", {"post": post})
```

Being that it is impossible for myself or anyone else to know what `post` contains, it is not possible for us to tell you exactly how to fix the issue. However, the issue lays in the repetition of this code:

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="{{ post.image.url}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="{{ post.title }}">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="{{ post.title }}">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="{{ post.title }}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Clearly, you are using the same `post.image.url` variable for all three carousel-items. Assuming a `post` object can be multiple images, then something like so should work:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for image in post.images %}
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="{{ image.url}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="{{ post.title }}">
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Bro that didn't work. The problem is that i want to take info from tha db and i am getting that info but its rendering its 3 times. I am using the generic views in django.

Answer (score 0):

I also facing same problem fetching carousel image from databases but it is showing only first image and when i click to next button slider not changing.

So don't warry friends i resolve the problem
First think is in carousel image you can use the code like this using for loop instead copy three image tag

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}">
        <img src="{{ post.image.url}}" class="d-block w-100" alt="{{ post.title }}">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="{{ post.title }}">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" class="d-block w-100" alt="{{ post.title }}">
    </div>
</div>
```

In this code i only chane in the carousel, your problem is your slider not changing ,so do this changes definitely your skider will work.

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}">
```